# KOMA-Script titlepage header and footer

Tags: titles, koma-script, fancyhdr

I have titlepage header and footer created by fancyhdr and I'm trying to replace it by koma-script solution.

I tried scrlayer-headings, but I just can't make koma-script print header or footer at titlepage environment. It works for all other pages, except titlepage.

Fancyhdr style

```
\fancypagestyle{titlepage_style_ru}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \chead{<some text>}
    \cfoot
    { \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\centering \opt@title@city@ru\\ \opt@title@year@ru} }
}
```

which I setup like this

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \thispagestyle{titlepage_style_ru}
     ....
```

Is it possible to achieve same behavior in koma-script for titlepage?

[Here's full WE](https://github.com/sanyarnd/sfedu-mmcs-latex-thesis-template)

Comment: Please don't use external links for a not minimal example. Always add the code of a minimal but working example to your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the following MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext} % dummy text

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % instead of fancyhdr
\ihead{ihead}
\ohead{ohead}
\chead{chead}
\ifoot{ifoot}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\ofoot{ofoot}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{scrheadings}
  \Huge This is a title page
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

which gives the following titlepage:

[image: title page]